VB.Net Loading Simple xml file to DataTable
I am having trouble getting vb.net to load an xml file into a datatable for use in a datagridview and other text elements. I have tried most of the solutions I could find over the last 2 days of searching but nothing seems to work. From what I can tell this should be just a simple DataSource.ReadXML command but when I do this and then set the DataGridVew1 datasource nothing shows up. I have tried multiple combos of reading to the DataTable and DataSource but cant get either to work.
I'm not sure what the correct approach is here. Should I be using 'ReadXML' into the DataSet or DataTable? If I read into the DataSet how does the data get into the correct table? Right now I am only working with 1 table but once I get this figured out I will need to read data from multiple different xml files and put them into different DataTables.
Here is a sample of the xml file I am using. I shortened it since there are approx 100 records in the document. This xml file was generated in excel to save time from typing everything out:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BlankData  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <SizeNum>#1 - 45</SizeNum>
        <Height>8</Height>
        <Top>3</Top>
        <Bottom>7.75</Bottom>
        <Weight>0</Weight>
        <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
        <Wrap>false</Wrap>
    </record>
    <record>
        <SizeNum>#1 - 90</SizeNum>
        <Height>8</Height>
        <Top>1.75</Top>
        <Bottom>11.25</Bottom>
        <Weight>0</Weight>
        <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
        <Wrap>false</Wrap>
    </record>
    <record>
        <SizeNum>#10 - 45 </SizeNum>
        <Height>20</Height>
        <Top>4.875</Top>
        <Bottom>16.75</Bottom>
        <Weight>0</Weight>
        <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
        <Wrap>false</Wrap>
    </record>
    <record>
        <SizeNum>#10 - 90 </SizeNum>
        <Height>14</Height>
        <Top>1.125</Top>
        <Bottom>19.5</Bottom>
        <Weight>0</Weight>
        <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
        <Wrap>false</Wrap>
    </record>
    <record>
        <SizeNum>#11 - 45 </SizeNum>
        <Height>23</Height>
        <Top>6</Top>
        <Bottom>21.375</Bottom>
        <Weight>0</Weight>
        <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
        <Wrap>false</Wrap>
    </record>
</BlankData>

I added this xml file to the project by adding a new xml file item and naming it BlankData. There is also a DataSource called PressData with a Table called BlankData and it has 7 columns with names that match the above xml sample. Not sure if its correct to have the ml file and datatable share the same name, before this iteration I had a differnt name for the xml file and tablename but I couldnt get it to work so I decided to try giving them the same name
I have tired to load the xml to the datasource with the below code
PressData.ReadXml(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\BlankData.xml")
DataGridView1.DataSource = PressData

which results in a blank datagridview box
and tired loading the xml to the datatable inside the datasource with this code
PressData.BlankData.ReadXml(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\BlankData.xml")
DataGridView1.DataSource = PressData.BlankData

which results in the datagridview showing the 7 columns but no row data.
I have tried a few other minor changes which I cant get to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try?
As I said earlier this seems like it should be simple but nothing I do seems to make a difference in the results, it is awlays one of the two cases above.
Is it possible I have a problem with the xml file?
Thanks for the help!
Daryan

The best way to debug issues with deserializing (ie: reading) XML, is to serialize (ie: write it to file) it. There are many ways to work with XML. Start by creating some test data and use it to create a XML file. You should use a method similar to what you plan to use to deserialize the data.

To load xml data, you should use a dataset, and not a datatable.
When the xml is read, then the dataset (which is a collection of tables) will load the data into the first table in the dataset.
So, I just pasted  your data into a test txt file.
Hence this code:
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sFile As String =
        "c:\test\test2\data.txt"

    Dim dt As New DataSet
    dt.ReadXml(sFile)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)


End Sub

And the result is this:

So, using a dataset works just fine. A dataset in place of a datatable is required, since xml imports can result in multiple tables.
Given your data only results in one datatable, then using the first datatable in the dataset array, and assigning that to say the example datagridview works fine as above shows.

Thanks for your response! I got it to work now using the dataset. I think my issue was in referencing the datasource of the gridview. In your example you use '0' which I assume is the first table, I just tested using DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables("record") and that also worked. So if I want to load multiple tables into the dataset would I include each table in the xml with a unique child element,then readxml like you show above, then use the data with the name or corresponding number?

Context "multiple" datasets would assume ONE xml file. If you need to load a given xml file over and over, then use the ReadXML method over and over for each new separate xml file. "multiple" tables feature is intended for single xml file that "might" have multiple tables in the xml data.  So concept here is some xml data file may well represent more then one table. Say a xml file as  single invoice. In that xml invoice data, you may have the name, address, billing (one table), and then you might have repeating rows of details (another table).  So to load one xml file you use Readxml each time

If the xml already has multiple tables (not just repeating rows to one table like your example), then a single Readxml will produce multiple tables.  There is no "concept" or feature here that hints, or suggest that if you have multiple xml files, then you would try to load all of them into a single dataset. If they are separate xml files, then you use a new ReadXML each time. If you have multiple xml files of the same one table, then you have to use read xml, save/send the data to a table, and then readxml the next file.

Thank you Albert that makes much more sense!

Here is an example.  First your data.
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = <BlankData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
             <record>
                 <SizeNum>#1 - 45</SizeNum>
                 <Height>8</Height>
                 <Top>3</Top>
                 <Bottom>7.75</Bottom>
                 <Weight>0</Weight>
                 <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
                 <Wrap>false</Wrap>
             </record>
             <record>
                 <SizeNum>#1 - 90</SizeNum>
                 <Height>8</Height>
                 <Top>1.75</Top>
                 <Bottom>11.25</Bottom>
                 <Weight>0</Weight>
                 <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
                 <Wrap>false</Wrap>
             </record>
             <record>
                 <SizeNum>#10 - 45 </SizeNum>
                 <Height>20</Height>
                 <Top>4.875</Top>
                 <Bottom>16.75</Bottom>
                 <Weight>0</Weight>
                 <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
                 <Wrap>false</Wrap>
             </record>
             <record>
                 <SizeNum>#10 - 90 </SizeNum>
                 <Height>14</Height>
                 <Top>1.125</Top>
                 <Bottom>19.5</Bottom>
                 <Weight>0</Weight>
                 <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
                 <Wrap>false</Wrap>
             </record>
             <record>
                 <SizeNum>#11 - 45 </SizeNum>
                 <Height>23</Height>
                 <Top>6</Top>
                 <Bottom>21.375</Bottom>
                 <Weight>0</Weight>
                 <TrimmedWeight>0</TrimmedWeight>
                 <Wrap>false</Wrap>
             </record>
         </BlankData>

Then create a dataset and read the XML.  Nothe the table name.
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds.ReadXml(xe.CreateReader)
    Debug.WriteLine(ds.Tables(0).TableName) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Then assign the only table in this to the DataGridView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

EDIT:
to load from a file instead of the literal.
    Dim xe As XElement
    Dim URI As String = "????????????"

    xe = XElement.Load(URI)


Thanks for your response. In our above example is the xelement creating the xml file?

@Daryan - no.  See the edit.
